# Lots of really great questions recently

Tags: discussion

Which makes me suspicious tbh. Do y'all have access to beta editions of chat-gpt? I believe it is unlikely that the quality of the site has suddenly quadrupled+, not without LLM assistance.

What do us mere mortals do about it?

Comment: Sharing some examples might be helpful ...

Comment: Aren't LLM better at answering than at asking questions actually?

Comment: i have no idea @Johan i'm sure you can get them to ask questions though

Comment: I do not see a lot of good questions lately. I see a lot of speculative questions without any prior research that invite or explicitly ask for opinions but not much I would upvote without a second thought. There is more overall activity, though, which may be seen as a good development.

Comment: i saw the opposite @PhilipKlöcking but only over the past two or three days